# Rails 5 and AJAX - can't do autocomplete and saving a nested form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, autocomplete

There is a model of teams in which there are a lot of users. Users are associated with the model of teams like `has_many :through`.
Need to make a field autocomplete when searching for users and adding nested fields when you select a user.

**app/controllers/teams_controller.rb**

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /teams/new
  def new
    @team = Team.new #(parent_id: params[:parent_id])
  end

  # GET /teams/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /teams
  def create
    @team = Team.new(team_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @team.save
        format.html { redirect_to @team, success: t('.flash.success.message') }
      else
        format.html { render :new, danger: t('.flash.danger.message') }
      end
    end
  end

  # GET /teams/1/search_team_user
  def search_team_user
    @users = User.order(:first_name).where("first_name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
    render json: @users.map { |u| { value: u.id, label: u.name } }
  end

  # GET /teams/1/new_team_user
  def new_team_user
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    @new_team_user = @team.team_users.build(user_id: params[:user_id])
  end

  private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def team_params
      params.require(:team).permit(
        :name,
        :parent_id,
        team_users_attributes: [:_destroy, :id, :user_id]
      )
    end
end
```

**app/config/routes.rb**

```
resources :teams do
  get :search_team_user, on: :member
  get :new_team_user, on: :member
end
```

**app/views/teams/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@team) do |f| %>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='<%= column_class %>'>
      <div class='form-group row'>
        <div class='<%= dynamic_small_column_class %>'>
          Team membership
        </div>
        <div class='<%= dynamic_large_column_class %>'>
          <div id='team-user-select' class='new-nested-group mb-3'>
            <%= text_field_tag 'search_team_users', nil, class: 'form-control autocomplete autocomplete-search new-nested-object', data: { autocomplete_object_id: true, autocomplete_source: search_team_user_team_path(@team), new_nested_object_path: new_team_user_team_path(@team) } %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag 'user_id', nil, class: 'autocomplete autocomplete-value new-nested-object' %>
          </div>
          <div id='team-users' class='nested-objects'>
            <%= render 'team_user_fields', f: f, team_users: @team_users, child_index: nil %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.form-group.row -->
    </div><!-- /.col -->
  </div><!-- /.row -->
  <hr class='my-5'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='<%= column_class %>'>
      <div class='pull-right'>
        <%= cancel_link %>
        <%= save_link %>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.col -->
  </div><!-- /.row -->
<% end %>
```

**app/views/teams/new_team_user.js.erb**

```
$('#team-users').append("<%= j(fields_for(@team) { |f| render('team_user_fields', f: f, team_users: @new_team_user, child_index: Time.now.to_i) }) %>");
```

**app/assets/javascripts/nested_form.coffee**

```
# # Autocomplete plagin
#
$.fn.customAutocomplete = ->
  @each (i, el) ->
    el = $(el)
    el.autocomplete
      minLength: 1
      source: el.data('autocomplete-source')
      focus: (event, ui) ->
        el.val ui.item.label
        false
      select: (event, ui) ->
        el.val ''
        el.next('.autocomplete.autocomplete-value').val ui.item.value

        url = el.data("new-nested-object-path")
        data = $('.new-nested-group :input, .new-nested-object').serialize()

        $.ajax
          url: url
          data: data
          dataType: 'script'
        false

# # Delete nested item
removeNestedObject = (element, objName) ->
  $("[name='"+objName+"[_destroy]']").val true
  $(element).closest('.removable-nested-object').remove()

$(document).on 'click', 'a.remove-nested-object', ->
  objName = $(this).data('object-name')
  removeNestedObject(this, objName)

# # On load
#
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->

  $('a.add-nested-object').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()

    url = @href
    data = $('.new-nested-group :input, .new-nested-object').serialize()

    $.ajax
      url: url
      data: data
      dataType: 'script'

  $('.autocomplete.autocomplete-search').customAutocomplete()
```

This code generates this error at the transition to the team new page:

> Showing
>   /Users/nikolaylipovtsev/Documents/Projects/inbox_task/app/views/teams/_form.html.erb
>   where line #23 raised:
>
> No route matches {:action=>"search_team_user", :controller=>"teams",
>   :id=>#, :locale=>:ru} missing required
>   keys: [:id]

What needs to change?

Answer (score 0):

The following route means a team with a valid `id` is required

```
get :search_team_user, on: :member
```

In the new team page, `@team` is created with `@team = Team.new` so its `id` attribute is nil. That's exactly what the error says

> No route matches {:action=>"search_team_user", :controller=>"teams", :id=>#, :locale=>:ru} missing required keys: [:id]

In `TeamsController#search_team_user`, I can see that this action doesn't need a team to run correctly. So to fix the problem, you can change your route to

```
resources :teams do
  get :search_team_user, on: :collection
  get :new_team_user, on: :member
end
```

Comment: Yes, but team [:id] need for TeamsController#new_team_user. This is need for correct save association.

Comment: @NikolayLipovtsev Look at the routes, `new_team_user` is still on member.

Comment: And this path `new_team_user` is in the new view, which will raise an error `<%= text_field_tag 'search_team_users', nil, class: 'form-control autocomplete autocomplete-search new-nested-object', data: { autocomplete_object_id: true, autocomplete_source: search_team_user_team_path(@team), new_nested_object_path: new_team_user_team_path(@team) } %>`

Comment: @NikolayLipovtsev If business logic states that a new user must be associated with a team. Showing a link to create a new user in the team "create" form just doesn't make sense because there's no team to associate the new user with. Doesn't it make more sense to only show that link when you edit a team?